# CSS transition to move image in from right

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an interesting situation that I was wondering if I can solve with CSS transition.

The best way to describe it is to have a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuEGv/5/).

You can see that when you hover over the title bar the text box and the image move across.

However, this is done by setting the X background position to above 100% which makes things go a bit mental!  Try resizing the browser width to see what I mean.

You can do this from the left - see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuEGv/6/) but I can't think of a CSS way to do it from the right.

I was thinking this could be done in the future with `calc()`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div inside nav as a hook for kitten background, float it right and animate the width on hover... With a little tweaking it works..

http://jsfiddle.net/RuEGv/7/

Comment: Great fiddle but doesn't quite do what I would like to do.  I'd like the image to slide in.  I think I have figured this out another way but requires a special image

Comment: If you want to whole image to slide in then there's no alternative than move the whole div with position absolute as you tried in the first place.. I guess the bug is due to the fact that when you resize your browser window somehow the percentage of the background position is based on the original viewport size thus miscalculating?..

Comment: Yeah setting percentage values outside of 0-100 seem to do some mental things.